# Mailto UTM tracking e-mail link

Tags: html, google-analytics, analytics

I have to track a link inside a mailto href. I Need the link inside the e-mail body to be tracked with a UTM. Any possible ways I can go about adding this without showing the utm link part in the e-mail?

Example below

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=subject&body=body http://www.example.com?utm_source=EmailShare&utm_medium=EmailShare&utm_term=EmailShare&utm_content=research&utm_campaign=website ">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But (like most e-mail marketing vendors do) you can create a redirect address that you use in your email and that adds the tracking parameters when it redirects to the destination page (or does the the tracking and then redirects).

Comment: Alright thank you, and thanks for a possible solution.